# How get Attribute Value in CodeAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4

I wrote a method to get Attribute Value By Property:

```
public string GetAttributeValueByNameAttributeAndProperty(CodeClass cc, string nameAttribute, string nameProperty)
{
    var value = "";
    foreach(CodeAttribute ca in cc.Attributes) 
            { 
                if(ca.Name.Contains(nameAttribute) && ca.Value.Contains(nameProperty))
                {
                    value = ca.Value.Remove(0,ca.Value.IndexOf(nameProperty));
                    value = value.Replace(" ","");
                    if(value.Contains(","))
                        value = value.Remove(ca.Value.IndexOf(","));
                }
            }

     return value;
}
```

**For Example:**
I have Attribute  `[Map(Name = "MenuItem, Availability" )]`

I call GetAttributeValueByNameAttributeAndProperty( codeclass, "Map" , "Name")
After that method get CodeAttribute.Value and return string: Name = "MenuItem, Availability"
After I remove "Name = " and  extra characters and Split by ","

But my Senior Programmer told me that this method is inflexible and I need to find a more convenient way get inner data in CodeAttribute.Value.

Do you have any ideas / examples?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I was looking for a way to read attribute values using code model. Then I came to your question and since it didn't have an answer so I posted one.  I know the question is rather old and probably you don't need the answer anymore, but future readers may find it useful :)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution :) Hope it will help anybody :) 
I eventually rewrote my t4 script into another script using Roslyn, since Roslyn provides a deep analyser of classes, attributes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CodeClass.Attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeclass.attributes.aspx) property to get attributes of a class. Each attribute is of type of [`CodeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeattribute.aspx) and has a [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeattribute.name.aspx) and a [`Children`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeattribute.children.aspx) property which contains arguments of the attribute. Each argument is of type of [`CodeAttributeArgument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.codeattributeargument.aspx) which has [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeattribute.name.aspx) and [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.codeattributeargument.value.aspx) properties.

**Example**

Now you have all information which you need to get attribute value from `CodeAttribute`. Here is an example. I've decorated `Program` class with a `[MySample(Property1 = "Something")]`  attribute

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleSample
{
    [MySample(Property1 = "Something")]
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
    public class MySampleAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the sample `T4` template:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDte" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDte80" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #> 
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE80" #> 
<#    
var env = (this.Host as IServiceProvider).GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
var project = env.Solution.FindProjectItem(this.Host.TemplateFile).ContainingProject
    as EnvDTE.Project;
var codeClass = project.ProjectItems.Item("Program.cs").FileCodeModel.CodeElements
                       .OfType<CodeNamespace>().ToList()[0]
                       .Members.OfType<CodeClass>().ToList()[0];
var attribute = codeClass.Attributes.Cast<CodeAttribute>()
                         .Where(a=>a.Name=="MySample").FirstOrDefault();
if(attribute!=null)
{
    var property = attribute.Children.OfType<CodeAttributeArgument>()
                            .Where(a=>a.Name=="Property1").FirstOrDefault();
    if(property!=null)
    {
        var value = property.Value;
        WriteLine(value);
    }
}
#>
```

If you run the template, you will receive `"Something"` in output.